# Refresh tiles in windows 7 after scheduled code execution

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

Is it possible to execute arbitrary code in fixed intervalls with Windows 7 phone? I try to do that and then refresh the tile image of my application. I need the arbitrary code execution, as it performs calculations that are neccessary to update the tile.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to have code in the app on the phone be guaranteed to run at fixed intervals when the application is not running as applicaitons cannot run in the background.

If you want to update the count displayed on the tile you can only do this through a [push notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402558%28VS.92%29.aspx).

If you want to periodically update the tile image, you can do this with a [tile schedule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769548%28VS.92%29.aspx). This will tell the tile to refresh the image at the specified interval. The idea is that you host the image on your server and regenerate it as needed to display up to date information.

The maximum frequency a schdeule will run at is hourly. If you need updates more often than this then you'll have to use notifications.

Answer (score -1):

You can execute code in fixed intervals by using the Timer class. Since you want to update UI elements I suggest that you use the DispatcherTimer since it will execute on the UI thread and therefore is allowed to update UI elements. It is described here:
[DispatcherTimer (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx)

Here is some code on how to use the DispatcherTimer (taken from the MSDN article):

```
dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
dispatcherTimer.Start();
```

If you mean the start page tile, the tile that starts the application - then it is a bit trickier. You'll have to use push notifications and that adds some more complex aspects to it. There is a training course about push notifications here:
[WP7 Training Kit - Push Notifications](http://channel9.msdn.com/Learn/Courses/WP7TrainingKit/WP7Silverlight/UsingPushNotificationsLab)

Yochay has a series of good posts regarding push notifications aswell:
[Understanding Microsoft Push Notifications for Windows Phones](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/05/03/understanding-microsoft-push-notifications-for-windows-phones.aspx)